# Check if roscore is started in C++

Tags: c++, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, what is the best way for a C++ application to check if roscore has already been started? I think I would like to avoid doing a system() call. Catching exceptions is also an undesirable feature for me because I am working on a Qt application. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36733/check-if-roscore-is-started-in-c++/) by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1396 on 2012-06-18

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is the roscpp API function [ros::master::check()](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1master.html#a6428e7e3468e4e9ab69b75f75d63510d). Note that you have to call `ros::init` before. `ros::init` won't block, instantiating a ros::NodeHandle will block and wait for the core though.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6